# Antlr parser SQL how to distinguish between a field and a table?

Tags: sql, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I write some Antlr4 rules to parse SQL,just want to distinguish between fields and tables.But they did something unexpected.My rule:

```
grammar Col;
stat : SELECT select_list FROM table_ref_list;
select_list : select_ele (',' select_ele)* ;
select_ele : Subquery_in_field_nor    //subquery select column
            | ID '(' .*? ')'  //function calls
            | NoDotId '(' .*? ')' NoDotId '(' .*? ')'  //window function call
            | ID             //like column of tab
            | DIGIT          //number
            | STRING         //like this 'dad'
            ;


table_ref_list
    : table_ref (',' table_ref)*
    ;

table_ref:table_block (NoDotId)?;

table_block : ID                   //So much like select_ele
          | Subquery_in_field_nor
          ;

Subquery_in_field_nor : '(' (Subquery_in_field | ~[()])* ')';  //Resolving function nesting
Subquery_in_field : '(' .*? ')' ;
SELECT : [Ss][Ee][Ll][Ee][Cc][Tt];
FROM :[Ff][Rr][Oo][Mm];
NL : [ \r\n]+ ->skip;
ID : [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9.]*;
NoDotId : [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9]*;  
DIGIT : ('-')? [0-9]+('.' [0-9]+)?;
STRING : '\'' .*? '\'';
```

And my sql file like this

```
SELECT substr(A.EMPNO,1,2),
       A.ENAME,
       '1',
       'wwet',
       18,
       A.DEPTNO FROM EMP A
```

Display message

```
line 1:13 missing FROM at '(A.EMPNO,1,2)'
line 3:7 mismatched input ''1'' expecting {Subquery_in_field_nor, ID}
line 4:7 mismatched input ''wwet'' expecting {Subquery_in_field_nor, ID}
line 5:7 mismatched input '18' expecting {Subquery_in_field_nor, ID}
(stat SELECT (select_list (select_ele substr)) <missing FROM> (table_ref_list (table_ref (table_block (A.EMPNO,1,2))) , (table_ref (table_block A.ENAME)) , (table_ref (table_block '1')) , (table_ref (table_block 'wwet')) , (table_ref (table_block 18)) , (table_ref (table_block A.DEPTNO))))
```

I don't know why ?Why i user `select_list : select_ele (',' select_ele)*` ,but still Match table_ref?

Answer (score 0):

`substr(A.EMPNO,1,2)` is not matched as a `select_ele` because it produces the tokens:

- `ID`: `substr`
- `Subquery_in_field_nor`: `(A.EMPNO,1,2)`

and not by any of the two alternatives:

- `| ID '(' .*? ')'  //function calls`
- `| NoDotId '(' .*? ')' NoDotId '(' .*? ')'  //window function call`

The part '(' .*? ')' is interpreted as: match a `(` token, reluctantly followed by zero or more other tokens, ending with a `)` token. But because ANTLR's lexer tries to grab as much characters as possible when tokenising the input, `(A.EMPNO,1,2)` will always be matched by a single `Subquery_in_field_nor` token.

Besides the greedy tokenisation in the lexer, you must also be aware that when 2 or more lexer rules can match the same characters, the one defined first "wins". So the input `select` can be matched by `SELECT`, `ID` and `NoDotId`. But since `SELECT` is defined first, that input will always become a `SELECT` token. However, the input `foo` can be matched by `ID` and `NoDotId` and since `ID` is defined first, it will win. You'll notice that there will never be a `NoDotId` token at all since whatever it matches is also matched by `ID`.

Here is a slightly modified grammar that works for your input:

```
grammar Col;

stat
  : SELECT select_list FROM table_ref_list
  ;

select_list
 : select_ele (',' select_ele)*
 ;

select_ele
 : id Subquery_in_field_nor (id Subquery_in_field_nor)?
 | id
 | DIGIT
 | STRING
 ;

table_ref_list
 : table_ref (',' table_ref)*
 ;

table_ref
 : table_block id?
 ;

table_block
 : id
 | Subquery_in_field_nor
 ;

id
 : ID ('.' ID)*
 ;

Subquery_in_field_nor : '(' (Subquery_in_field | ~[()])* ')';  //Resolving function nesting
Subquery_in_field     : '(' .*? ')' ;
SELECT                : [Ss][Ee][Ll][Ee][Cc][Tt];
FROM                  : [Ff][Rr][Oo][Mm];
NL                    : [ \r\n]+ ->skip;
ID                    : [A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9]*;
DIGIT                 : ('-')? [0-9]+('.' [0-9]+)?;
STRING                : '\'' .*? '\'';
```

Or better, grab an existing SQL grammar from the ANTLR4 Github repo: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 Be aware that all of these grammars are opensource contributions from the community: test them properly, because many of them will have limitations (both in accuracy and in performance).

Comment: Oh,bro.Thank you very much.I've been a little busy at work, and I haven't had a chance to get back to you.Thank you for your help.I didn't use GITHUB mainly because  only supported native functions when parsing fields, and I was a novice and wanted to wait and see more than 10,000 lines of code

Comment: Hello,brother. I'm here for some help. I've been trying all day. I've been trying to figure out what antlr4 syntax to use to distinguish between () after an insert and any function call